# VNC viewer does not refresh the screen

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vnc

I am connecting from a windows 7 VNC to a linux VNC, everytime I connect I can move the mouse and type. I can confirm this because I see it on the server. However the screen does not refresh. It show the initial screen when it connects, but when opening a menu, I can see the menu opening on the server, but on my vnc it doesn't. I have to close the viewer and relaunch it to get the refreshed screen (after which it freezes again to that frame). I am on a local Gbit network.

client : windows 7
server : ubuntu lucid lynx 10.04.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling desktop effects made it work normal again. (system -> preferences -> apearences ->visual effects)

Comment: Consider marking this as an accepted answer by clicking on the outline of a checkmark next to this post so that others who run across this question know that it has been answered.

Comment: I'll do that when I can which  is in two days :p

Comment: This answer didn't work for me. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use VNC anymore, mainly SSH+X11 forwarding, so I can't really help with 10.4... but I had the same problem with previous ubuntu LTS (8.04), and it was an issue whti compositing windows manager (compiz) enabled.

As compiz since become install default, try going back to metacity to see if it solves your issue (you can install compiz fusion icon to make this a one click job)?

Comment: What server and what client are you using? Not all are interoperable.